# how to use the muse to get aligned embedding

Tags: nlp

Resently, I used the MUSE to align en-zh embeddings. By this way, I get 5 files as the result of the MUSE, three of which are vectors-en.txt, vectors-zh.txt and best_mapping.pth. How do I use the three files to get the alignment file? Or how to represent chinese embeddings and english embeddings in a common share space?